# Custom conditional operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Say I have the following construct appearing frequently in my code,

```
if (e.which==13){ ... }
```

...and I would like to make the code look a bit cleaner by writing instead:

```
ifEnterPressed{ ... }
```

Is there a way of defining an operator such as `ifEnterPressed` in Javascript?

## Update

I have figured out that the basic issue is that Javascript does not support syntactic macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the solution with a function, you can use an object for grouping and keeping the keycodes, like

```
KEY = {
    enter: 13
}
```

Usage:

```
if (e.which === KEY.enter){ ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

No you can't define a custom operator like that.

You can of course write a helper method though:

```
function enterPressed(e) {
    return e.which==13;
}
```

And then:

```
if(enterPressed(e)) {
    // yay!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that in Javascript, but you can use a function:

```
function isEnter (e) {
  return e.which === 13;
}
```

Then

```
if (isEnter(e)) {
  // do something!
}
```